# How do i style a div with no ID or Class, that is also inside of a dynamically changing ID div (JS modal pop-up)

Tags: css

To start, I know how to style a div with a dynamically changing ID, being created from a JS call. I also think I know how to style a div without an ID or Class. But combining the two I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the structure and code

```
<div id="windowManager_75b500eb-3139-4670-9c36-7bf0cd88672a">
    <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c">
        <div class="jsframe-titlebar-focused" id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_title">
            <span id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_titleBarText"></span>
        </div>
    <div id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas">
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_RD"></span>
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_DD"></span>
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_RR"></span>
        <div>
            <span>✖</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div in question is the final one that is housing the `<span>x</span>`. It is an button to close the modal window. I need to override the CSS values currently given to that field (from a JS script) using CSS. The tricky part for me is that every other div surrounding it have IDs that are dynamic and change, so I have to use certain CSS to call those.

Here is what I tried:

```
  [id^=window_] > div:nth-child(1), 
  [id^=window_ i] > div:nth-child(1),
  [id*=window_] > div:nth-child(1), 
  [id*=window_ i] > div:nth-child(1) {}
```

And tried

```
[id^=windowManager_][id^=window_] > div:nth-child(1), 
[id^=windowManager_][id^=window_ i] > div:nth-child(1),
[id^=windowManager_][id*=window_] > div:nth-child(1), 
[id^=windowManager_][id*=window_ i] > div:nth-child(1) {}
```

unfortunately, the above CSS didn't target anything.

Comment: Is the parent div id static or dynamic the one with id = "window_..." ?

Comment: @Sameh It is dynamic. All of the IDs in my above code are dynamic. but there are parts that are static. For the long string of letters and numbers are dynamic. but the front and or back of the IDs are static. Example is windowmanager_ and window_ are static.

Comment: Does `[id^=windowManager_] > div > div` work for you? There is only 1 child div of `windowManager` (the other child is a span), and then again there is only 1 div, the rest are spans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[id^=windowManager_] > div > div` *should* work however the markup is missing a closing `span` which is messing up selectors

```css
[id^="windowManager_"] > div > div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="windowManager_75b500eb-3139-4670-9c36-7bf0cd88672a">
    <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c">
        <div class="jsframe-titlebar-focused" id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_title">
            <span id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_titleBarText"></span>
        </div>
    </span> <!-- ⭐️ this closing span is missing? -->
    <div id="window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas">
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_RD"></span>
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_DD"></span>
        <span id="htmlElement_window_c5888687-e892-4441-aa9c-0adb5b22bf1c_canvas_RR"></span>
        <div>
            <span>✖</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very neat, I liked it, I tried solving it with jQuery and simple css but I didn't know we can do the same kind of selection in css, nice to know

Comment: Thanks! This got me close. The solution was [id^=windowManager_] [id^=window_] > div Same concept but added an identifier where i could. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is suggested answer, You have to tweak it a little to make it work but I am just giving an idea here

1- Try to get the div with the dynamic Ids that starts with window, it can be done via JQuery, this may return 0 or n div elements depends on how many div match the criteria

```
$('[id*="_windowManager_"]')
```

2- Assign a css class to your last div element[desired one] call the css class for instance window-manager, you can do this also using the jquery once you have the desired element

3- In your css define the following css

```
div.window-manager span {
  come css attributes 
}
```